# Add two dates in C++

Tags: c++, c, time, ctime

I'm sure this question is answered elsewhere, but I cannot find it on Google or SO, so here goes.

In C/C++, I want to convert a relative time in format dd-hh:mm:ss provided by

```
ps -o etime
```

to an absolute UTC formatted date.

This doesn't seem like it should be very hard. Supposing I have already got a function to produce the relative time stored in struct tm format:

```
struct tm *starting_rel_time = my_reltime_converstion(...);
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm *current_abs_time =  localtime(&t);
```

what I want is basically the opposite of difftime:

```
struct *tm starting_abs_time = current_abs_time - starting_rel_time;
```

Now, I can write my own function to do the conversion, but it's a nightmare because of all the carry operations and special conditions (leap years etc.). Surely there is a way to do this in the C/C++ libraries?

Comment: You can take a look at boost date time library. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? They are different languages, with different libraries available for each.

Comment: To clarify: I would prefer to write it in C, or with the C-like C++ libraries (e.g. time.h), but could use other C++ libraries if they do the job better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `DD-HH:MM::SS` to seconds with simple math; it's relative-time, so just multiply and add.  Then, query the `current time()` in seconds (assuming it's "relative to now"), and add them.  Then use `gmtime` to convert back to a `struct tm`.

Comment: I would recommend *strongly* against doing it my hand, you will miss DST adjustments as well as time adjustments.  There is a reason we have things like the parsing in the standard libraries.

Comment: OP said days-hours-minutes-seconds is a relative time... there is no DST and time adjustments in a relative time.  3 days is 3 days, period.  Any time adjustments between time and the relative time is handled by gmtime.  Also note: there is no DST in UTC.

Comment: This is what I wanted, approximately. It is surprising that there isn't a native function for doing this with tm structs though. Seems like a fairly common thing to want...

Answer (score 3):

Use [Boost::Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time.html) libraries.

Comment: Or the standard [chrono library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) if this is really a C++ question

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That doesn't handle dates and calendars.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such language as C/C++.

If you're asking about C, I suggest representing dates internally with a simple numeric type, and converting to and from `struct tm` only when necessary. If you only need to cover a few decades, then you could use `time_t` and convert using the standard `gmtime` and `mktime` library functions. To cover a wider timespan, you could use a [Julian day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) representation.

If you're asking about C++, I suggest the [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time.html) library. Of course, the C library functions are still available if they meet your needs.

Comment: `mktime` and `gmtime` are part of standard C++, and probably sufficient for what he wants to do.  C++11 adds quite a bit of additional functionality, based on Boost, I think.  (I've not had the time to study the standard versions, but the Boost stuff was very well designed.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The C++11 chrono library doesn't include any date or calendar handling; you'll need Boost (or whatever) if the C library doesn't suffice.

Comment: So I see (having since looked it up).  The fact that you can't convert to and from a day/month/year representation sort of limits its utility.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.  You cannot add two dates.
(And `difftime` doesn't return a date, nor a `time_t`.)

In practice, on most, if not all implementations, `time_t` will be an
integral type with the number of seconds since some specific "epoch".
On such machines, you can add or subtract an integral number of seconds
from a `time_t` to get a new time, at least if all of the times you're
interested in are in the interval supported by `time_t` (roughly between
1970 and 2038 on most Unix platforms).  This, along with `gmtime`, 
`mktime` and `localtime` is probably sufficient for your needs.  Note
especially that `mktime` is required to "correct" it's `tm` input: you
can, for example, take a `tm`, add 5 to the field `tm_mday`, call
`mktime` on it, and get the correct values for a date five days in the
future—all of the necessary carry operations and special
conditions are handled in `mktime`.

*If* this is not sufficient, C++11 has both a `time_point` and a
`duration` class, with (from a quick glance) seems to have all of the
functionality you could possibly need.